# sql multiple join (right. left, inner) to mongodb aggregate

Tags: mongodb, aggregates

//I have a sql like this

SELECT

x.attr1,
p.attr2,
p2.attr3,
o.attr4,
p2.attr5,
a2.attr6

FROM TABLE_O o

RIGHT JOIN TABLE_A a ON a.id = o.id AND a.id2 IS NULL

LEFT JOIN TABLE_A a2 ON a2.id = o.id  AND a2.id2 = a.id3

LEFT JOIN TABLE_P p ON a.id4 = p.id4

LEFT JOIN TABLE_P p2 ON a2.id4 = p2.id4

INNER JOIN TABLE_X x ON a.id3 = x.id3

WHERE o.type = 'someText' AND a2.id4

IN ( SELECT id3 FROM TABLE_P WHERE TYPE = "anotherText")

AND x.attr1 = "someText"

//I need an idea about how can i do this on mongo aggregates, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

nosql is a non-relational database type. but The following link may be useful.

[mongodb aggregation](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/mongodb/mongodb_aggregation.htm)